# Complex number expansion proof

Tags: calculus

$1+\text{cis}(x)+\text{cis}(2x)+\text{cis}(3x)...+\text{cis}(nx)=$

### ${\dfrac{1-\text{cis}(n-1)x}{1-\text{cis}(x)}}$

Where $\text{cis}(x)=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$

I have tried representing $\text{cis}(x)$ as $e^{ix}$, and using demoivre, but have gotten nowhere.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

Check the relation for $n=1$:

$cis(x)=\frac{1-cis((n-1)x)}{1-cis(x)}$

So we get: $cis(x)=\frac{1-1}{1-cis(x)}=0$. It follows, that the relation is not valid in general.

Are you sure that the formula is correct?

Comment: Wow I didn't even think of actually seeing if the relationship actually worked.  I will ask my math teacher tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will denote $\text{cis} (x) \equiv e^{ix}$. De Moivre's formula is very natural in this form since $\left(e^{ix}\right)^n=e^{inx}$. Then your series becomes

$$ e^{ix}+e^{2ix}+...+e^{nix} = \sum_{k=1}^n e^{ikx} $$

which is a geometric series. For a general geometric series we have

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n a_0 q^k = \frac{a_0 (1-q^k)}{1-q}$$

so your series becomes (with $a_0=q=e^{ix}$)

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n e^{ikx} = \frac{e^{ix} (1-e^{inx})}{1-e^{ix}} = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{i(n+1)x}}{1-e^{ix}} $$

Notice the difference from your formula. Also note that this formula gives the correct result for $n=1$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would have never thought of using a geometric series! I was trying all these pointless factoring methods.  Thanks again. If you ever need a kidney, I've got you.

Comment: @Cameron You're welcome. For a start, you could accept my answer :) That way your question won't show up as "unsanswered".

Answer (score 0):

I see now why the answers you guys are getting are different from the answer given in the problem.  The problem has it as 1+cis(x)+cis(2x)+cis(3x)...+cis(nx), and I forgot to include the 1 when I wrote it.  So, the first term isn't e^(ix), it's really 1, or e^(0ix).

I also made a mistake in writing it as 1−cis(n−1)x/1−cis(x) when it should have been 
1−cis(n+1)x/1−cis(x) Sorry for the confusion, but you can now get the answer the book gave, and it works for n=1 when you use demoivre. Thanks for the help everybody!